# Can't get MVVMCross core project to reference System.Xml.Linq

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm quite new to MVVMCross but I've been actively using it for two weeks, at work and in a school project, and I am really enjoying it! Unfortunately, I've been stuck on the school project for 2 days now : we're asked to do a mobile Jabber client. This is not a big deal since I started it using Matrix XMPP library, which does most of the job and is easy to use. I decided to restart my project using MVVMCross, in order to have cleaner separated code and add a Windows Phone project, but Matrix absolutely needs System.Xml.Linq, and I can't get the core PCL to compile :

```
The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

As shown in Stuart Lodge's tutorial videos, I'm using profile 104, the the faulting dll is really present in the folder, I can't add it manually to project's references since VS prevents me from doing it (gently explaining that it's automatically loaded since .Net portable subset is included in references), I've updated and repaired my VS install "just in case"... and have no more idea left.

So, here are the questions :

- is it really possible to use System.Xml.Linq with MVVMCross? or did I miss the big title  explaining that what I'm trying to do is stupid?
- if yes (that'd be great!) did/does someone experience the same problem? Even more interesting : did someone find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Additional info : Windows8(x64), VS2012 Ultimate, trial license (school project...) for Xamarin.Android

---

**UPDATE :** following Stuart's answer, I compiled and ran the *BestSellers* sample, which uses System.Xml.Linq... without any problem.  As it comes with an explicit reference to `System.Xml.Linq` (see [first link in answer](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers.csproj#L49)), I tried :

1. to delete it (and a few others) : VS holds it's promises, and really includes needed references as long as `.Net Portable Subset` is referenced, so everything rolls smooth.
2. to manually add this reference via Notepad to *my* .csproj : it doesn't change anything.

One thing tickles me in Stuart's answer : *"perhaps it is something to do with the way the matrix uses XML.linq"*. Since the Matrix type I'm trying to use is just a descendant of `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, which is widely used in *BookViewModel.cs* [from sample](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers/ViewModels/BookViewModel.cs#L44), what could possibly be wrong with that?

---

**"Solution" :** The problem seems to be due to Matrix requiring a special version of `System.Xml.Linq`, which is not the one included when profile 104 for building PCL. I used [file linking](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options) method as a workaround to share the core, and that works, though this is less elegant, readable, and harder to maintain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use at least some of System.Xml.Linq

For example, see the BestSellers sample

- csproj file - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers.csproj#L49
- example XML linq use - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers/ViewModels/BookViewModel.cs#L44

For the problem you are seeing, I'm really not sure what the error is - perhaps it is something to do with the way the matrix uses XML.linq? You might have more luck of you open up this question to other tags like portable-class-library, XML-linq and windows-phone.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the `PCL` tag, but XML-Linq doesn't exist, and I don't think the issue is WP-related. I tested the linked sample, and updated the question

Comment: OK - I tried to help. At least now you have a sample that works and a sample that doesn't - maybe you can spot what the differences are.

Comment: Late note : adding Matrix to the BestSellers sample reproduces the problem, so the problem is really not from MvvmCross. Seems Matrix uses a particular version of System.Xml.Linq, which isn't the one used when building with MvvmCross... so I guess you were right, it's something to do with the way Matrix uses it. Not what I was hoping, but an answer anyway. Thanks! :)